# How to manage shared files

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, version-control, mercurial

I would like to find the best way to manage and version our shared files. Now we use mercurial with TortoiseHG for this, which is good for version all files in one project, but what we want to handle some files separately from the main repository.

We use codeigniter and we have some model, library and view files what we want to share between our projects and version these files separately from the current project in other repository (or something other way, for example with package manager - i don't no what could be the best).

With other words, We have Project A and Project B (we have lot more project than two, this is only for example). When we get a feature request, which is a general feature (better login system) from the owner of the Project B, we prepare the necessary changes, and we would like to upload this modification to all other project. Now we create these modifications in the current project, where we are working on. It could be hard to develop if we create an other third project with it's own repository to these shared files, because these files do not work alone, so they need other view, and controller files to load and test them.

Structure:

```
root/
  application/
    model/
      auth.php
      other1.php
      other2.php
    library/
      mail.php
      other1.php
```

So we want to auth.php and mail.php version separately, than other.php-s and upload to other place from any of our project, and check is there any update in these separated repository of shared files and if is there, than update these files in there own project.

What i tried so far: i created a subrepository in mercurial, but as i see, it is only work if we hold our shared files in separated folder, which is not that, what we want.

With subrepository we got these structure:

```
root/
  .hg/
    ...
  application/
    model/
      auth.php
      other1.php
      other2.php
    library/
      mail.php
      other1.php
  subrepo-files/
    application/
      model/
        auth.php
    library/
        mail.php
```

I hope you understand what I'm saying, because it is more and more difficult to treat. Now what we do is, we manually copy these shared files to all other project, when one of them updated. And yes this is terrible! Sometimes somebody forget to copy the updated version of the shared files to other project, and when we create other changes in other project on a shared file, and than copy them back to other projects we lose previous updates (which is versioned with is own project, but we only noticed too late, and we have to debug them manually).

I spent cupel of days to find the best way for this, but i didn't found exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.  What I've done in the past for things like this is use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) and [private Composer repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own).  With Composer you can package your shared code as a "module" (or whatever you like to call it).

For example, we have a in-house DB module and config module that we use all over.  For those I can manage and update the DB or config module independently and then include them in whatever project needs them.

The really cool part is you can [*version*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version) your Composer modules.  This means that each app which loads the module, only pulls in a specific version of it.  If you update the module, the other apps are still using the previous version and don't all break.

I know this doesn't solve the problem of how do you develop and test the modules per say, but there are some options.

Composer will load the module in a `vendor/` directory inside your current application.  Once loaded into your app you can either swap out the Composer-loaded module code with a symlink to your module's separated project files or you could modify them in the `vendor` directory and then push the change up to Mercurial.

You could also create a pared-down test/mock version of your MVC app and automate tests there.

Comment: In this case we should to reorder our/ci file/folder structure and this is not what we can do. unfortunately :(